# Abusing analytic continuation

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

I'm playing with math I only partially understand, which means I know enough to be dangerous.  Why doesn't this transformation work?  I wasn't necessarily expecting it to but I also don't understand where a mistake was made.

First, take an equation with real valued variables and coefficients:

$$x + y = 2 \ b$$

$$e^{\log(x)} + e^{\log(y)} = 2 \ e^{\log(b)}$$

Now extend the equation in the complex plane by introducing a new parameter $s \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the equation is analytic in the open unit disk (at least) and the analytic continuation of the function at $s=1$ gives us the original equation:

$$e^{s \log(x)} + e^{s \log(y)} = 2 \ e^{s \log(b)}$$

Now break the exponents into infinite series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^n \frac{\log(x)^n}{n!} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^n \frac{\log(y)^n}{n!} = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} s^n \frac{\log(b)^n}{n!}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{s^n}{n!} \left( \log(x)^n + \log(y)^n\right) = 2 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{s^n}{n!} \log(b)^n$$

The equality should hold for all $s$, so equate the various terms of the infinite series:

$$\log(x)^n + \log(y)^n = 2 \log(b)^n$$

This holds for all values of $x, y, b$ at $n=0$.  So far so good.  However at larger values of $n$ this breaks down.  For instance, there's a counter example if $x = e^2, y = e^4$.  First solve for $b$ at $n=1$:
$$\log(e^2) + \log(e^4) = 2 \log(b)$$
$$2 + 4 = 2 \log(b)$$
$$b = e^3$$

but then:
$$\log(e^2)^4 + \log(e^4)^4 = 2 \log(e^3)^4$$
$$2^4 + 4^4 = 2 \cdot 3^4 $$
$$16 + 256 = 2 \cdot 81 $$
$$272 = 162$$

Which isn't true.  So I made at least one mistake somewhere.  What is the mistake?  I assume it's in how I set up the extension into the complex plane?

Comment: There is no function to analytically continue. You moved from $x+y=2b$ to $x^s+y^s=2b^s$ which is false

Comment: When creating the extension to the complex plane is there a way to determine if it's allowed/legal?  I was just requiring that when $s=1$ you get the original equation, but that's insufficient.

Comment: You need to define a function first!

Comment: Apologies, I'm not sure what you mean exactly.  My goal is to create a new equality embedded in the complex plane with a new parameter $s$ such that you get back the original equality when $s=1$ and you can deconstruct the equality into an infinite series on each side of the equals sign.  The idea is related to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Conformal_mappings except I'm sort of playing it backwards trying to get a series out instead of starting with a series.

Comment: Look up the "[identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)". Analytic continuation rests on this principle. You need: a simply connected open subset $D\subset\Bbb C$ (a "domain"), an analytic $f:K\to\Bbb C$ where $K\subset D$ is a non-hollow set. The theorem goes, if $g$ is any analytic function on $D$ and $g=f$ on $K$, then $g=f$ on all of $D$. So... I don't see any of this set up on $x+y=2b$ "implies" $x^s+y^s=2b^s$. Indeed, the set of values on which it may hold is $s\in\{1\}$ and $\{1\}$ is most definitely a hollow set

Comment: Analytic continuation, or rather the *uniqueness* of analytic continuation as provided by the identity theorem, is a beautiful and powerful idea but it isn't magic; you do need to satisfy the theorem. You can't say: true for $s=1$ implies true for all $s$

Comment: Alternatively to “K is not hollow” you can demand that K had a cluster point, in the sequence sense, I think

Comment: thankyou, I think that was the piece I was missing.  I don't think I've heard of a hollow set before (I'm coming from this more from a complex analysis direction and less from a topology direction), but it sounds like a necessary (if maybe not sufficient?) condition for the complex embedding is that there's a neighborhood where the equality holds, not just single points.

Comment: Yes there is; more precisely, what the proof requires is that there is a point $c$ such that, for any disc centred at $c$ which fits into $D$ ($D$ is open so this is ok) there must exist a point in that disc where $f=g$ (topologically one says $c$ is a cluster/limit/accumulation point of the set $\{z\in D:f(z)=g(z)\}$. When I first learnt the identity theorem I had to give myself a quick crash course in the necessary topology. You need a sufficiently “large” set to guarantee uniqueness (as is maybe intuitive) - “large” doesn’t mean literally big, but it does mean infinitely many points!

Comment: (And those points have to cluster together somewhere) Non-hollow sets are a good example for this (the one I had in mind before) since they by definition contain a point $c$ so that sufficiently small discs about $c$ are fully contained in the set